# Dual HVAC System with Dual UV lights - looking to power UV lights when HVAC runs

Tags: hvac, relay

So I have
(2) HVAC systems in the attic
(2) UV Lights in the attic ducts downstream of the blower(s) (powered by a standalone 120v outlet)

I would like to power the UV lights when the HVAC / blower is running

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated,

Comment: Could you post a photo of the furnace controller and wiring diagram? The controller is usually found in the blower compartment; the wiring diagram is often a large sticker on the inside face of the blower compartment door.

Comment: Yes, can you post wiring diagrams for your furnaces/air-handlers?

Comment: Ok - sorry for the delay - attempting to add photos

Comment: The unit on the right is a older Carrier unit
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tv394kliri8paj5/IMG_20200620_135732.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ec8t47ewi7cqbhq/IMG_20200620_135726.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/94xgqfivu8zm18j/IMG_20200620_135716.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3lzf34xa5sa09n/IMG_20200620_135619.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/416j3uezxalbzgr/IMG_20200620_135510.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rq7hbiixpzdjx3o/IMG_20200620_135319.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The unit on the left is a newer Amana unit
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9q3labybkz5jxj/IMG_20200620_135250.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pe3l0dr1r777knd/IMG_20200620_134949.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uteg1hi5o4ncs4w/IMG_20200620_134921.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/inw4j3203xf98ge/IMG_20200620_134912.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lfufmjb01mexmit/IMG_20200620_134903.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzxjrb8u81x7fpg/IMG_20200620_134857.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9web2dcj4e4nuja/IMG_20200620_134825.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @GregHill please find linked photos

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel please find linked photos

Comment: @MikeP. How much current do these UV lamps pull?  Also, can you post photos of the junction boxes where the UV lamps are plugged in at?

Comment: The units use 36w bulbs 
https://www.odorstop.com/os36-36-watt-uv-air-treatment-system-with-16-bulbs/

The face plate reads "120v 36w"

@ThreePhaseEel

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], @MikeP! Pro tip for the future, instead of hosting the images in your Dropbox account, you can upload them and let SE host them for you by clicking the "sun and mountains" icon above the Question edit box. This will also display the images in the question and save people a lot of time clicking back and forth - makes it much easier on them. Please take the [tour] and browse the [help] to find out more about how to make the most of site.

Answer (score 1):

The wiring diagram for the Amana unit appears to show a connection for an optional mains-powered electronic air cleaner. This might be just right for your use. You'll have to find literature from the furnace to confirm how much power that connection can support, confirm that terminals you can use are available on the circuit board, and confirm that the power requirement of the UV lamps is compatible with what the furnace control can provide.

The Carrier unit is a little more clear about its support for an electronic air cleaner. The legend printed under the wiring diagram shows terminals EAC-1 and EAC-2 are for powering an air cleaner at 115 V with current up to 1.5 A. I'd guess those terminals are going to be 1/4" blade quick-connect type.

For both systems you'd have to check the manuals, or simply experiment, to discover when the control turns on the EAC output.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like they can power the UV bulbs directly off the EAC outputs of the furnaces in question, even

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how elaborate you want to get with this.  You could mount an air flow paddle switch in the duct work, cord it into a junction box where it ties into the UV light fixture cable and feed the box from your 120V outlet. You'd need one setup for each HVAC system.

[image]

Comment: I am not opposed to simple and effective - how expensive are they ? A quick google search puts them around $75ea (if I am looking at the right items)